# Get value from one activity to another one

Tags: android

How can I use `savePreferences` and `loadPreferences` methods
In **first activity**

```
private static final String GLOBAL_PREFERENCES = "music_status";

public static void savePreferences(@NonNull Context context, String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(GLOBAL_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}...
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    musicGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupForMusic);
    turnOn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonMusicOn);
    turnOff = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonMusicOff);
    musicGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId){
                case R.id.radioButtonMusicOff:
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    savePreferences(MainMenuActivity.this,"music_status",0);
                case R.id.radioButtonMusicOn:
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    savePreferences(MainMenuActivity.this,"music_status",1);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

In **Second activity**

```
private static final String GLOBAL_PREFERENCES = "music_status";
public static int loadPreferences(@NonNull Context context, String key, int defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(GLOBAL_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, defaultValue);
}
```

However I do not know how to get the value from first activity

Comment: What is that exception? Post logcat

Comment: `MainMenuActivity.status`.. So this is a static variable? Note: Intents+Extras are recommended over static variables.

Comment: Try not to use an activity then. i would make a new class containing the needed values and have both activities implement that class.

Comment: Could you explain how you have two activities but are not navigating between them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Comment: This is the exception "FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: loc.nwd.splitball, PID: 2506
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void loc.nwd.splitball.musicStatus.setStatus(int)' on a null object reference"

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is **you cannot do that**. Unless your `status` variable is static. Which is extremely bad for this case.

You have three choices.

### SharedPreferences

In contrast to my previous revision. This might be the best option for your case.

If you only want to save the state of something, you might find it better to simply not use a class to hold the status of your music. You could do as @cricket_007 suggests and implement `SharedPreferences`.

You could use these example functions:

```
private static final String GLOBAL_PREFERENCES = "a.nice.identifier.for.your.preferences.goes.here";

public static void savePreferences(@NonNull Context context, String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(GLOBAL_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public static int loadPreferences(@NonNull Context context, String key, int defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(GLOBAL_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, defaultValue);
}
```

You can then use those functions in your code to save the status of your music. Instead of `status.setStatus(0);` and `status.setStatus(1);` your can use `Utils.savePreferences(context, "music_status", 1);` and instead of `status.getStatus()` you could use `Utils.loadPreferences(context, "music_status", 0);`

### Parcelable

[One option for you is to implement](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) `Parcelable` in your `musicStatus` class. You can then send the object through an Intent to your second activity. You may find an example class implementing `Parcelable` below.

Once you have that, you can pass it through Intents like so:

```
musicStatus status = new musicStatus();
status.setStatus(8);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HighScoreActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("status", status);
startActivity(intent);
```

Class implementation:

```
public class musicStatus implements Parcelable {
    private int status;

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status){
        this.status = status;
    }

    private musicStatus(Parcel in) {
        status = in.readInt();
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(status);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<musicStatus> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<musicStatus>() {
        public musicStatus createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new musicStatus(in);
        }

        public musicStatus[] newArray(int size) {
            return new musicStatus[size];
        }
    };

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

### Singleton

In this case, this would really be an anti-pattern. However, it is still a possibility.

```
public class musicStatus {
    private static musicStatus mInstance = null;
    private int status;

    @NonNull
    public static musicStatus getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            synchronized(mInstance) {
                if (mInstance == null) {
                    mInstance = new musicStatus();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int getStatus(){
        return status;
    }

    public  void setStatus(int status){
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: `SharedPreferences` would be another potential option

Comment: yes, "public static musicStatus status;" I forgot to paste

Comment: Don't do that @BohuaJia: That will cause the `Activity` `Context` to leak. Since the static `musicStatus` will be referenced permanently!

Comment: I am just learn android, can u tell me how to use `public class musicStatus implements Parcelable` thank u very much

Comment: @BohuaJia Please re-read my answer. I modified it. I added a reference to SharedPreferences, because it might well be better suited to your particular requirements. I also added a more fleshed out guide to Parcelable.

Comment: in shared preference, what is the value of context? thank you

Comment: `Context` can be the `Activity` you are currently in. If you are in your `Activity` most of the time `this` will work. In a pinch however, something like `MainMenuActivity.this` will work too. The `Context` class is extremely important. It is worth reading about as part of your learning about Android: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: Have no idea how to use loadPreference, as I saw the int variable defaultValue, but I have no idea how to set it, I just up load my question

Comment: I really can't make it simpler than I have. Unless you have a more targetted question, this is about as far as I can help you.

Answer (score 2):

For the easiest way, your musicStatus class need implement Serializable.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("musicStatus", status);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

in other activity:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

musicStatus status=
               (musicStatus)bundle.getSerializable("musicStatus");
```

Comment: this one doesnt work, it will navigate to second act

Comment: public class musicStatus implements Serializable {
      //your code
}
Have you done this?

Answer (score 0):

extend `Serviceable` in you POJO class.

After while starting Activity 2.

```
  intetn.putExtra("obj",pojoObj);
```

and get it in you second activity using.

```
PojoCls obj = (PojoCls)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("obj");
```

Thats it.